# How to start Azure VM(Deallocated) use REST API

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I found a very strange problem here:
In Azure powershell, we can use 
Start-AzureVM -ServiceName "mypc" -Name "mypc"
for both VM state= stop  or stop(Deallocated).
But for Azure Mangement API
We can use [start role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157189.aspx) only for VM state= stop

VM state=stop(deallocated) can't use that API..
How can I use REST API to start VM with State=Stop(deallocated)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlets use the Service Management REST API - but it uses an [undocumented](http://convective.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/setting-an-endpoint-acl-on-a-windows-azure-vm/) 2013-06-01 version. It is possible that this operation is available only in the undocumented version of the Service Management REST API.

You can see what the cmdlets actually do by using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS) to proxy the request - this gives you access to the operation invoked (URL) as well as the payload sent and received. Alternatively, you can look at the PowerShell cmdlets [source](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools) which is available on GitHub.

Comment: Hi 
I tried fiddler, but it doesn't work for me, because the proxy request will get 403 forbidden issue, the cmdlet will first send a get reqeust to get vm information then send post request, if you use fiddler you can only get the get request, then will cause the 403 issue, does I get any thing wrong?

Comment: Yes use **x-ms-version: 2013-06-01** can resolve the problem, but I still want to know how to use fiddler as proxy but not get 403 fobidden

Comment: You put your Windows Azure authentication certificate into %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Fiddler2\ClientCertificate.cer

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/RespondWithClientCert

Comment: I spent so many hours working on this, only to discover it is an undocumented api issue. Grr.

Answer (score 1):

```
POST https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roleinstances/<role-name>/Operations

**x-ms-version: 2013-06-01**

<StartRoleOperation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><OperationType>StartRoleOperation</OperationType></StartRoleOperation>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Task<ComputeLongRunningOperationResponse> StartVirtualMachineAsync(string subscriptionId, string name, string resource_group)
{
    TokenCloudCredentials tokenCloudCredential = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token);

    ComputeManagementClient computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(tokenCloudCredential);

    return computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.StartAsync(resource_group, name);
}
```

Comment: This code depends on deprecated libraries