# How to turn on/off Azure virtual machine via Azure management api (rest)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I want to create a start/stop Azure VM bot for myself. What I want to do is to have a slack/telegram bot that listens to messages and starts/stops my VM by commands /start/stop. What REST api command should I use to do that?

**What is needed:**

Some sample code in C# that calls azure management API to start deallocated virtual machine

Some reference where I can get values for API method parameters (e.g. subscription id, resource id, etc).

**Also**

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065253/how-to-start-azure-vmdeallocated-use-rest-api) question, but it didn't help me to understand how to deal with authorization and where to get those parameters.

I am creating that bot using C# language.

Comment: Add more details about what you want to achieve. The link you try to post does not works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> calls azure management API to start deallocated virtual machine

[Virtual Machines REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines) lists the operations on virtual machines. To start a virtual machine, you can try [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-start):

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm}/start?api-version={apiVersion}
```

> where I can get values for API method parameters (e.g. subscription id, resource id, etc).

You can find `{subscriptionId}` and `{ resourceGroup}` on Azure portal.

[image]

> how to deal with authorization

You can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/index#create-the-request) to get started with Azure REST operations and request authentication. And you can refer to the following code to acquire an access token.

```
string tenantId = "{tenantId}";
string clientId = "{clientId}";
string clientSecret = "{secret}";
string subscriptionid = "{subscriptionid}";

string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential: credential);

if (result == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
}

string token = result.AccessToken;
```

Besides, this article explained how to [create AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application), please refer to it.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!